# ElasticSearch pagination--Does ES count from 0 or from 1?

Tags: elasticsearch, count, pagination

I'm using pagination in a series of ES filters. in the first page i set `from = 0`, `size = 10000`. My question is in the next page do i used `from = 10000`, `size = 20000`, or do i use `from = 10001`? I suspect it's `from = 10000`, but don't want to duplicate or drop a hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GET /_search?size=5
GET /_search?size=5&from=5
GET /_search?size=5&from=10
```

When `size=5` and `from=5` it skips 5 and produces a result of 6,7,8,9,10.

More detail: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html

So in your case for `from=10000` it actually starts from 10001.

Comment: and in my case, I don't change the `size` parameter? so the second page is `from = 10000` and still keep `size = 10000`, right?